# Не получается задеплоить проект

Tags: php, linux

На работе дали старый скрипт к 3у деплоеру. Вроде все нормально, но вылетает `[RuntimeException]   Unable to login with the provided credentials.`
Подскажите, уже всю голову сломал.

P.S. первый раз имею дело с ssh, deploey'ом и все такое

Answer (score 0):

В репозиторий нужно добавить public key, перед этим его нужно сгенерировать, он будет выглядит примерно так, как [описано здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)